# SOLR '0' Status: Communication Error

Tags: solr

I am using SOLR for indexing documents.I create index from a mysql database. I create index from PHP which runs on wamp server. I am using SOLR PHP client to create index. When I create index from the server on which SOLR is deployed, everything works fine. But when I try to create index from a different machine, I get the following error:

**'0' Status: Communication Error**

I tried changing php socket time out, solr commitlocktimeout and solr writelocktimeout. But still I get the same error. When I create index from the solr server itslef, there is no error.

PHP version : 5.2.2
SOLR version : 1.4.1

Any idea on why this happens?

Thank you

Following is my stack trace:

```
'0' Status: Communication Error#0 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\library\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(672): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawPost('http://129.107....', '<add allowDups=...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\library\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(736): Apache_Solr_Service->add('<add allowDups=...')
#2 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\library\Nist\Console\NistSolrIndex.php(106): Apache_Solr_Service->addDocuments(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\library\Nist\Console\CrawlUNT.php(346): Nist_Console_NistSolrIndex->createIndex()
#4 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\library\Nist\Console\CrawlUNT.php(89): Nist_Console_CrawlUNT->CrawlParseAndIndexProfiles()
#5 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\Bootstrap.php(107): Nist_Console_CrawlUNT->run(Object(Zend_Console_Getopt))
#6 C:\wamp\www\nist\application\Bootstrap.php(78): Bootstrap->_runConsoleApp()
#7 C:\wamp\www\dkumar\mentis-libs\Zend\Application.php(366): Bootstrap->run()
#8 C:\wamp\www\nist\index.php(37): Zend_Application->run()
```

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: @user1959447 Please share with us your complete Solr stack trace.

Comment: I forgot to mention.When I add documents to SOLR, I add it in batches of 50. Because my table has a lot of records, I have to do in batches due to memory constraints. The 'Communication error' occurs only for some batches. For other batches, documents get added properly.

Comment: Did you find a solution that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue when we changed our password. It was caused by special characters in the new password. Removing '@', '/' '()' solved the issue.

Solr: 4.9, PHP: 5.6